# Debugging BASH IF Conditions

Tags: bash, debugging, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am getting an error when I try and run my assignment.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Assignment 2

echo Please enter a User Name:
read u
if [ $u!="root"]; then
        echo Searching for Username!
        grep $u /etc/passwd|sed 's/$u/hidden/gi'
elif [ $u!="toor"]; then
        echo Root is NOT allowed.
else
        echo Toor is definetely NOT allowed.
fi
```

Output:

```
Please enter a User Name:
user1
./assign2.sh: line 6: [bthiessen: command not found
./assign2.sh: line 9: [bthiessen: command not found
Toor is definetely NOT allowed.
```

What is wrong with my if statements?

Comment: Please, transcribe your errors. It will be easier for other users to find this post if they have the same problem.

Comment: Your answer is in [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). It's a great guide to keep around when trying to figure out Bash programming.

Comment: Sorry Victor, i am really new here. I think someone beat me to it! I was really confused trying to edit my own post.. when I realized it was already edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please enter a User Name:
read u
if [[ $u != "root" ]]; then
        echo Searching for Username!
        grep "$u" /etc/passwd | sed "s/$u/hidden/gi"
elif [[ $u != "toor" ]]; then
        echo Root is NOT allowed.
else
        echo Toor is definetely NOT allowed.
fi
```

**problems founds** :

- `[ $u!="root"]` need spaces around `!=`
- if you use variables in sed, you need `"` quotes, not simple `'`

**note** :

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals . Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`

Learn the difference between `'` and `"` and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: So why do I have to double [[ it? I don't understand why that is necessary.

Comment: It's not absolutely necessary, but `[[ ]]` is more powerful than `[ ]`.

Comment: Why does it need double quotes instead of single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace counts here:

```
if [[ $u!="root" ]]; then
```

And:

```
elif [[ $u!="toor" ]]; then
```

Also prefer `[[` over `[`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ $u!="root"]; then
elif [ $u!="toor"]; then
```

There needs to be spaces inside the square brackets, and around the `!=` operator. The whitespace is required. It's also good practice to quote `"$u"` in case the username has spaces or is blank.

```
if [ "$u" != "root" ]; then
elif [ "$u" != "toor" ]; then
```

There are other issues with your script which I suppose should be left to you to find.

Answer (score 1):

To debug bash scripts, you can also use `bash -x` and `set -x`:

`bash -x script.sh` runs an existing script with debug messages, it will echo lines before executing them.

With `set -x` you can enable this behavior directly in your shell script, e.g. in the first line after the shebang. (This is kind of like `echo on` in Windows scripting.) `set +x` disables this option.

It is even possible, although hardly useful, to `set -x` in interactive shells.

This is all nicely explained in the Bash Guide for Beginners, under [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).